# How to make node-red run 24/7 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, sh, node-red

I want to host node-red 24/7 on Raspberry Pi. Something was running it constantly, then, the power had gone out, then it came back. But, then, the data was not coming.
I want the node-red to run constantly (at least when the raspberry pi is running). I tried making an .SH file to make it constantly run, here is the code:

```
node-red
```

that is the command prompt line to run node-red.

That did not work, is there something that I can do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a process manager, there are many process managers available each with their own features.

Natively many linux distributions support this functionality via a system called `systemd` also called an `init` system.

*Docker as a system is also an option but this may be excessive for your use-case.*

---

**Some popular process manager applications are:**

1. [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)
2. [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

---

**Additional reading:**

[A supervisord tutorial on Digital Ocean by Alex Garnett](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps)

[A systemd tutorial on Digital Ocean by Justin Ellingwood](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units)

Comment: While useful as background information, for the actual OPs problem Node-RED already supplies a systemd script they have just not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The node-red install instructions for raspberry pi cover the in the running as a service section

https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/raspberrypi#running-as-a-service

It is most likely that you had used `node-red-start` to start Node-RED as a service, but you had not completed the latter step to enable the service to start on boot.

> **Autostart on boot**
>
> If you want Node-RED to run when the Pi is turned on, or re-booted,
> you can enable the service to autostart by running the command:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl enable nodered.service
> ```
>
> To disable the service, run the command:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl disable nodered.service
> ```